# Loop to fill NA's with means not working properly

Tags: r

I'm trying to fill all the NA's in my fields with the mean of each column.

The code I've been using is:

```
var1<-colnames(DF)

for (i in 1:length(var1)) {
  v<-paste0("`",var1[i],"`")
  DF<-DF %>%
      mutate(v=ifelse(is.na(v),mean(v,na.rm=TRUE),v))
}
```

After running this piece of code, nothing happens with the DF.

I already tried running for an individual column, and the code works:

```
DF<-DF%>%
mutate(col1=ifelse(is.na(col1),mean(col1,na.rm=TRUE),col1))
```

I'm using the ` in the paste part because some of the columns can have spaces between words and I cannot change this. I have the feeling that this part is where the mistake reside.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple columns use `mutate_at` (for all columns - `mutate_all`)

```
DF %>%
  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .)))
```

---

It can be made compact with `na.aggregate` from `zoo` (replaces the NA with the `mean` for each columns.  By default `FUN = mean`)

```
library(zoo)
na.aggregate(DF)
```

---

If we are using a `for` loop, then there is no need for a package.  Just update the column `NA` elements with the `mean` of that column

```
for(nm in var1) DF[[nm]][is.na(DF[[nm]])] <- mean(DF[[nm]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or with `lapply`

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Or using `colMeans`

```
DF[is.na(DF)] <- colMeans(DF, na.rm = TRUE)[col(DF)][is.na(DF)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 0:5), 20 *5, replace = TRUE), 20, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was sure there was a more elegant solution for this problem, and both are great.